# Protractor error: Expected null to equal 'some value'

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I'm testing non-angular site and have a problem with error message as: Expected null to equal 'some value'. I need to check a value (text) in inputs. The code of element is:

```
<input type="text" id="acc-form-14" data-required="false" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" value="Test name">
```

My test is:

```
let dataArr = [
    {id:"first_name", value1:"test Kate FN", value2:"test ANOTHER Kate FN"}
]

it("should check values", () => {

checkingValues();

    function checkingValues(){
        let data = dataArr[currentIndex];
        let el = element(by.name(data.id));

        el.getAttribute('value').then(text => {
            if (text === data.value1) {
                expect(el.getAttribute(data.id)).toEqual(data.value1);
            } else {
                expect(el.getAttribute(data.id)).toEqual(data.value2);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

That provides 
Expected null to equal 'test ANOTHER Kate FN'.
Why? If I change to getText(), I'll get the same error but 
Expected ' ' to equal 'test ANOTHER Kate FN'.

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(el.getAttribute(data.id)).toEqual(data.value1);
```

It appears that the data.id in the above line will equal to **first_name** but your element does not have an attribute of first_name. Could you try using the below code?

```
expect(el.getAttribute('value')).toEqual(data.value1);
```